# If you grow a div and shrink a div in the same column of divs simultaneously, how can you keep the vertical position stable?

Tags: jquery

Say I have a column of DIV siblings. A click on DIV 3 causes DIV 1 to "unexpand" and DIV 3 to expand (grow longer).  This is usually okay if DIV 1 and DIV 3 are about the same height when expanded and unexpanded. But if DIV 1 and DIV 3 are very different heights, then the the browser viewport shifts the mouse pointer away from DIV 3, which the user just clicked on.

I'm not sure if I'm explaining this clearly, but I think Google reader gets around this problem somehow when you expand a feed item and then expand another one that's below that one.

The question, again, is how do you keep the mouse pointer in the same position relative to the div that it just clicked on when the divs around it change in size?

I'm using jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not scroll the page? Using $("body").scroll() and $("div").offset() would be a start. That way, you could scroll the page in such a way (according to the div's original position) so that the cursor is still on it.